# Chained dropdown menu in cakephp 3

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, chained-select

I have 4 tables `categories`, `subcategories`,  `product_types` and `products`. Each is associated with other in following hierarchy.

```
categories
|- subcategories
   |- product_types
      |- products
```

The view of `add()` action of `ProductsController` is

```
        <?= $this->Form->create($product, ['type' => 'file', 'class' => 'ajax_page']) ?>
            <fieldset>
                <legend><?= __('Add Product') ?> <div class="ajax_loading_image"></div></legend>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('category_id', ['options' => $categories, 'empty' => true]);
                    echo $this->Form->input('subcategory_id', ['options' => $subcategories]);
                    echo $this->Form->input('product_type_id', ['options' => $productTypes]);
                    echo $this->Form->input('product_code');
                    echo $this->Form->input('SKU');
                    echo $this->Form->input('title');
                    echo $this->Form->input('description');
             </fieldset>
   <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Right now it is list whole `subcategories` in the list. I want to load `subcategories` on change of `categories` and `product_types` on change of `subcategories` using Ajax.

There is no good example I can found for CakePHP 3.x and also some documentation mentioned that js helper has been removed from CakePHP 3

How it can be implemented in CakePHP 3. I'm new to CakePHP and Ajax as well.

Thank You.

Comment: Tip: http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/chained-dropdowns :) It contains also the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ctp file as below. here first of all i give id to field categories,subcategories,producttype and productcode .

```
<?= $this->Form->create($product, ['type' => 'file', 'class' => 'ajax_page']) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Product') ?> <div class="ajax_loading_image"></div></legend>
        <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('category_id', ['options' => $categories, 'empty' => true,'id'=>'categories']);
                echo $this->Form->input('subcategory_id', ['options' => '$subcategories','id'=>'subcategories']);
                echo $this->Form->input('product_type_id', ['options' => '$productTypes','id'=>'producttype']);
                echo $this->Form->input('product_code',['options'=>'$productcode','id'=>'productcode']);
                echo $this->Form->input('SKU');
                echo $this->Form->input('title');
                echo $this->Form->input('description');
    </fieldset>     <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

and in your ajax call for subcategories is as below. you can create same ajax call for product_type and product code

```
<script>
    $("#categories").on('change',function() {
        var id = $(this).val();

        $("#subcategories").find('option').remove();
        if (id) {
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                dataType:'json',
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "yourcontroller", "action" => "youraction")); ?>' ,
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    //$("#loding1").hide();
                    $.each(html, function(key, value) {              
                        //alert(key);
                        //alert(value);
                        //$('<option>').val('').text('select');
                        $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#subcategories"));

                    });
                } 
            });
        }
    });
```

from this code you can get chained dropdown menu. its work for you.

Comment: what will be the code for action. I tried this but it is not working. I tried with action `public function getSubcategories()
    {
        $id = $this->request->data('id');

        $subcategories = $this->Subcategories->find('all', [
          'conditions' => [
            'category_id' => $id
          ]
        ]);

        echo json_encode($subcategories);

    }`

Comment: Thanks it works. There thing I missing was `$('<option>').val(value['id']).text(value['title']).appendTo($("#subcategories"));`